How does websocket work with load balancers
I am having lot of confusions around how websocket work with loadbalancers

Will loadbalancer work with websocket only with sticky session option? Because the message has to be sent to same server since the individual server will be holding the connection information?
If yes then what happens when we have servers added and removed from system since due to hash rebalancing request will go to different servers?

Some solution suggest to use L3 network layer load balancer. In that case how will SSL work?

The newer load balancers version have introduced websocket option which was not there earlier like amazon ALS, HAproxy. How does these loadbalancers work do they also need to maintain websocket connection to client and server? In that case how will loadbalancers scale?



Same as another other HTTP connection, but note that websocket connections don't survive the underlying TCP connection, so the question of connection keepalive doesn't arise.
